# How to find the controller corresponding to variable being used in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR. I am trying to make some changes in the views.

I have to override a variable in the view. But I am not able to figure out which controller sets the value of that variable. How can I find the controller corresponding to the variable?

Thanks

Comment: Derive from file names. If the view is `app/views/products/show.html.erb`, then I'm willing to bet that controller is at `app/controllers/products_controller.rb`

Comment: Use RDD - Regex Driven Development :) If the view doesn't exactly match controller as Sergio mentioned.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : i think I've got it, the view was `app/views/products/_ql.html.erb`. Correspondind variable is in `ql` function defined within `app/controllers/product_controller_decorator.rb`.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your view is rendered by a particular controller's action. You cannot have any other action rendered at the same time. Therefore, if you look at the controller in your URL, you should be able to work out the corresponding action accordingly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nish, I would also suggest adding this to your application.html.erb

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

It helped me learn alot about the process in rails and understand what was talking to what when I was viewing my application.

Hope it helps.